# Visual Studio 2010 RC is missing installed WPF Templates for certain project

Tags: visual-studio

only with a certain .Net 4.0 project I can not add a new Window item to my project in the solution explorer. In the installed Templates for WPF there is only the UserControl ?

What happened?

edit: In that direcotry => C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\WPF\1033

I can see all the wpf templates... so why aren`t they all shown in the WPF=>Installed Templates section?

I have done in the command shell with admin rights devenv /resetsettings, devenv /setup, devenv /installvstemplates and I reassigned the project templates/item templates path to the above itemTempaltes path and analog to the ProjectTemplate path where I could see all templates.

Nothing worked!?

Answer (score 0):

They don't appear because of your project type.

The solution, to quote [CoolDadTx](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/csharpide/thread/FE6C2172-0375-4AA9-B4A4-5ACA6CA4F795):

> If you select a WPF Custom Control or WPF User Control library then you should see the options.  If you use any other type of library then they don't show up as an option.  It isn't that you can't use them, just that they don't show up.